# Selenium(PYTHON) How to manipulate attributes

Tags: python, selenium, bots, webautomation

So this is more of a conceptual question, but im having trouble understanding whether or not i can manipulate the properties of a class, i understand how to navigate through the elements, but what if i want to in my case, make the element hidden, in the code below I have a for loop run through a bunch of coins that are classes that constantly dis/re appear on the screen so i have to count them before i can run through them all, hence 'count = len' but i made a print statement that even shows that the code runs through all the indexes properly, but they wont hide on the screen, what am i doing wrong

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('coinlist'))


for x in range(count):

    x += 1
    flip = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//ul[@class='coinlist']/div[{str(x)}]")
    flip.isdisplayed() = false
```

Comment: Are you trying to interact with the displayed page, or directly with the DOM? Either way, you can't use ```is_displayed()``` to set a property, it only returns ```True/False``` if the element is displayed on the page.

Comment: well its an image that is listed as a class, if you right click an element, theres an option called 'Hide Element' that is essentially what i would like to do with the program that i am writing

Comment: You have to use ```driver.execute_script()``` with JS code to do that, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `driver.execute_script()` with JS to modify the DOM.

```py
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('coinlist'))

for x in range(count):
    
    x += 1
    flip = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//ul[@class='coinlist']/div[{str(x)}]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','visibility:hidden;');", flip)
```

*Should* do the trick

Comment: So this cant be done in python? does that mean i have to rewrite everything else in java, or is there another alternative

Comment: because im getting an error "javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: It is python, except for ```"arguments[0].setAttribute('style','visibility:hidden;');"````

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the original, I forgot a '. It has been updated and should work. Any other errors, I will need to see more of your code.

Comment: yea it doesnt work, im not exactly sure why

Comment: the rest of the script is just imports and an explicit wait time

Comment: ooh my mistake, i just corrected the typo u were talking about, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\adamj\OneDrive\Desktop\python\test.py", line 38, in 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style',visibility:hidden;');", flip)
File "C:\Users\adamj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
return self.execute(command, {
File "C:\Users\adamj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\adamj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)